# Showing cellular data is turned off alert

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uialertview

How can I show this alert view? I know that I need check connection with reachability, but how do I show this alert with settings and ok button? 
I need it for iOS 6.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately in iOS 5.1 and later you can't open settings app from your app.

If you are using lesser version the following will work.

Create the Alert view like:

```
UIAlertView *cellularData = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Cellular Data is Turned Off" message:@"Turn on ellular data or use Wi-Fi to access data"  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Settings", nil];
[cellularData show];
```

Implement the `clickedButtonAtIndex` like:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
   if(buttonIndex == 1)
   {
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=General&path=Network"]]
   }
}
```

It'll open the settings app from your application.

Comment: this is ok only for ios 5 i need too for ios 6, do you have any idea?

Comment: I found information: In earlier iOS versions there was a url pattern that worked but Apple disabled that in iOS 5.

Comment: @RomanBarzyczak: I researched alot bases on your comment, and you are correct. The above won't work in iOS 5.1 and greater versions. You can't open the settings app from your app.